# Passing/storing arrays by reference?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm fairly new to javascript. I downloaded some code to make an autocompleter for search boxes, but it's not working as I expected it.

This is the code that I downloaded:

```
Autocompleter.Local = new Class({

    Extends: Autocompleter,

    initialize: function (element, tokens, options) {
        this.parent(element, options);
        console.log(tokens); // I added this
        this.tokens = tokens;
    },

    query: function () {
        console.log(this.tokens); // and this
        this.update(this.filter());
    }

});
```

To make use of this code, I do this:

```
var Activities = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'abcd'];

function InitializePage() {

    new Autocompleter.Local('txtSearch', Activities, {
        'minLength': 1, // We wait for at least one character
        'overflow': false, // Overflow for more entries
        'selectMode': 'type-ahead'
    });
}

window.addEvent('domready', function () {
   InitializePage();
});
```

The `tokens` parameter for the initialize function is an array of all the possible things that the autocompleter might suggest. the `filter()` function filters these so only relevant ones are displayed to the user. What I want to do is change the `tokens` array at various times so different things are suggested to the user.

I tried doing this:

```
new Request.JSON({ method: 'get', url: 'handler/GetActivities.ashx', autoCancel: true, urlEncoded: false, secure: false,
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
    onSuccess: function (_json, _jsonText) {
        Activities = _json;
    }
}).send();
```

I have confirmed that the `Activities` variable is being updated by this request. However, the `tokens` variable inside the autocompleter class remains as the array that it was initialized as.

How do I get it so that the `tokens` variable points to the same data as the `activities` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the array. You should replace the elements instead. You can add and remove elements in-place with [`splice` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
Activities.splice(0, Activities.length, _json[0], _json[1], ...);
```

This would remove all elements (from `0` to `Activities.length`) and add each element from the `_json` array.

But `_json` might contain an unknown number of elements, and hardcoding it like we did above is very bad. Fortunately, we can use the [`apply`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) method to call a method with a variable number of arguments, provided as array:

```
var params = [0, Activities.length].concat(_json);
Activities.splice.apply(Activities, params);
```

This is the equivalent to the call above, but adding all elements from `_json`.

**Reference:** [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this in entirely the wrong way. I had to stare at the splice/apply thing for 10 minutes to work out what was going on there though!

Comment: @Oliver: You're welcome :) FWIW, I explained it a bit better now.